# Find number in complex form.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Inspired from a recent question on SE, how to write:

> $2^{36}$ in complex form? To the power of $e$?

I thought since: $2 = 2e^{2k\pi i}$ that:

$2^{36} = 2^{36} 3^{72k\pi i}$

But the answer is:

$2^{36} = 2^{36} e^{2 k \pi}$

Why?

Comment: Unless the book is specifying that $k=0$, the book is wrong. You seem to have a typo; did you mean to write $e$ instead of $3$?

Comment: Presumably it means to say $2^{36} = 2^{36} e^{2k \pi i}$ for integers $k$.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to write $2^{36}$ as a power of $e$ is

$$2^{36}=\left(e^{\ln 2}\right)^{36}=e^{36\ln 2}$$

If you want all possible ways to do this in complex numbers,

$$2^{36}=e^{36\ln 2+2k\pi i}$$

for $k\in \Bbb Z$.